# C++ debugging with Visual Studio Code High Sierra

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to get c++ debugging working on mac os high sierra. Here is my launch.json file. I not really sure how to get it running.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/user/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/test",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I do hit the debug button Visual Studio Code will just show me the debug buttons and then will give me the following error message.

```
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/closure/libclosured.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/Users/jeffomidvaran/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/test'. Symbols loaded.
The program '/Users/user/Desktop/VSCodeProjects/test' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

Comment: What's in the program you're debugging? Does it just exit if you run it? Do you have any breakpoints set in the code?

Comment: I do have breakpoints. I was just running a simple for loop with the breakpoint inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time when people run into this problem it is because they have not compiled with debug symbols enabled. For clang, you can specify the `-g` flag and that will make the program debuggable. Without debug symbols, the debugger doesn't know the code to execution line information so it won't be able to set the breakpoint.

You can post over on our [Extension's GitHub site](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues) for more help.